# How to append end of file to a string

Tags: ocaml, eof

I just hit that "problem" : is there a smart way to insert the end of file (ASCII 0) character in a string?

By "smart", I mean something better than

```
let s = "foo" ^ (String.make 1 (Char.chr 0))
let s = "foo\000"
```

that is, something which would reflect that we are adding an EOF, not a "mystery char which ascii value is 0".

---

**EDIT**:
Mmh... indeed I was messing with eof being a char. But anyway, in C you can have

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a = getchar();
    if (a = EOF)
        printf("eof");
    else 
        printf("not eof");
    return 0;
}
```

Where you can test whether a char is an EOF (and `(int) EOF` is `-1`, not `0` as I was thinking). And similarly, you can set a char to be EOF, etc..

My question is: Is it possible to have something similar in ocaml ?

Comment: ASCII 0 is not "end of file". "end of file" is not a real character.

Comment: Why do you need that for? What is it you actually want to do with it?

Comment: Bromind I'm very eager to learn more about the problem you hit, that you call "that problem". Please don't be embarrassed about thinking that EOF was a character. I've been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C has two errors. First, you assign EOF to `a` instead of comparing `a` with EOF. Second, `getchar()` returns an int. It returns an int expressly so that it can return EOF, a value not representable by a char. Your code (with the first error corrected), which assigns `getchar()`s value to a char before testing it, will fail to process a file with a char of value 255 in it:

```
$ gcc -Wall getchar.c -o getchar
$ echo -e "\xFF" > fake-eof
$ echo " " > space
$ ./getchar < fake-eof
eof
$ ./getchar < space
not eof
```

The trick with `getchar` returning int, of returning a larger type so that your return can include the smaller type and alternately other kinds of information, is a trick that's wholly unnecessary in OCaml due to its more advanced type system. OCaml could have

```
(* using hypothetical c_getchar, a wrapper for the getchar() in C that returns an int *)

let getchar_opt () =
  match c_getchar () with
  | -1 -> None
  | c -> Some (char_of_int c)

let getchar_exn () =
  match c_getchar () with
  | -1 -> raise End_of_file
  | c -> char_of_int c

type `a ior = EOF | Value of 'a

let getchar_ior () =
  match c_getchar_ior () with
  | -1 -> EOF
  | c -> Value (char_of_int c)
```

Of course `Pervasives.input_char` in OCaml raises an exception on EOF rather than doing one of these other things. If you want a non-exceptional interface, you could wrap `input_char` with your own version that catches the exception, or you could - depending on your program - use `Unix.read` instead, which returns the number of bytes it was able to read, which is 0 on EOF.

Comment: whops, my bad for the "=" in the if. Indeed, I never realised that getchar is returning an int to do a "char or something else".

Answer (score 6):

As @melpomene says, there is no EOF character, and '\000' really is just a character. So there's no real answer to your question as near as I can tell.

You can define your own name for a string consisting of just the NUL character (as we used to call it):

```
let eof = "\000"
```

Then your function looks like this:

```
let add_eof s = s ^ eof
```